# Remove Google Chrome Unique ID on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, privacy, id

I've seen ways to remove the Google Chrome unique ID on Windows using tools like "unchrome" but after a bit of searching I am unable to find an equivalent tool on Linux.  Can anyone provide any useful information on removing this unique ID in Linux distros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, it is in your Local State file.

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Local State
```

Look for `user_experience_metrics` (on mine it's near the bottom of the file) then `client_id`. Take that out and you should be good.

Comment: Just to be sure...This won't be regenerated next time I launch chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. It would have the same behavior as on Windows. It would be pretty trivial to test. Is there a reason you really want to get rid of it?

Comment: Not particularly..just trying to stop giving Google my life :)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know exactly the same thing. Things like this should not be enable by default. + If your behind a VPN for anonymity reasons google will still be able to track you